# FastAPI error: output is a list of lists (or list of dictionaries) with defined variables types -- 'keywords must be strings (type=type_error)'

Tags: python, fastapi

Side note: there may or may not be extra libs loaded in below scripts. Shouldn't matter much though.

In FastAPI/docs with 'try it out' button, the inputs for the Request body is:

```
{
  "region": "US",
  "start_date": "2019-01-01",
  "end_date": "2020-12-31"
}
```

The main code is three files below:

```
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from helpers.response_models import HolidaysIn, HolidaysOut # script below
from pydantic import BaseSettings
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ValidationError
import uvicorn

@app.post("/enrich/get_holidays", response_model=List[HolidaysOut])
async def get_holidays(hi: HolidaysIn):
    holidays: list[HolidaysOut] = Enrich.get_holidays(region=hi.region,
                                                      start_date=hi.start_date,
                                                      end_date=hi.end_date)
    return holidays

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host=uvi_host, port=uvi_port, reload=True, root_path=api_settings.base_path)
```

```
# enrich.py
from helpers.response_models import HolidaysIn, HolidaysOut
from workalendar.core import Calendar
from workalendar.registry import registry
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
from datetime import datetime


class Enrich:
    @classmethod
    def get_holidays(cls, region: str, start_date: str, end_date: str) -> List[HolidaysOut]:
        # Init
        CalendarClass = registry.get(region)
        calendar = CalendarClass()

        # Get the range of years
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

        start_year = start_date.year
        end_year = end_date.year

        all_years = range(start_year, end_year + 1, 1)

        # Get the holidays for each of the years
        list_holiday = list()

        for yearr in all_years:
            list_holiday.append(calendar.holidays(yearr))

        # Convert list of three lists of tuples -> list of lists
        final_list = []
        #for inner_list in list_holiday: final_list += [list(inner_tuple) for inner_tuple in inner_list] # List of lists
        for inner_list in list_holiday: final_list += [{inner_tuple[0]: inner_tuple[1]} for inner_tuple in inner_list]  # List of dicts

        return final_list
```

```
# response_models.py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date

class HolidaysIn(BaseModel):
    region: str
    start_date: str
    end_date: str


class HolidaysOut(BaseModel):
    date: date
    name: str
```

```
#> Error
#first version: value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
#second version: keywords must be strings (type=type_error)
```

So I have tried two versions of this code. The first one is commented out in `main.py`, where `final_list = []` is a list of lists. The second version is list of dicts.

I'm really stuck on this problem. Is my output not defined correctly?

Comment: show what returns `final_list`? because static `List of dicts` worked for me with that pydantic model

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Thanks for the comment, but I'm unsure what you mean. `final_list` should return a list of lists/dicts, depending on which line you uncomment. It's the whole FastAPI response model that does not work due to the error indicated in the post.

Comment: When I return statically `[{"name":"money", "date": date.today()},{"name":"sany", "date":date.today()}]` from `get_holidays()` in Enrich class, it works

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Sorry I don't understand. How are you returning this exactly? I don't understand how `[{"name":"money", "date": date.today()},{"name":"sany", "date":date.today()}]` would be an output of the class/function.

Comment: Have you look at what the output of your `get_holidays()` function actually is and compared that to your correct, static example?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed some of your business logic code and tried with sample static data to check if everything is working or not? Posting what I see working here. Also I think you have an issue with the calculation of `final_list` that's why it is showing errors.

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from response_models import HolidaysIn, HolidaysOut
import uvicorn
from enrich import Enrich
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()
@app.post("/enrich/get_holidays", response_model=List[HolidaysOut])
async def get_holidays(hi: HolidaysIn):
    holidays: list[HolidaysOut] = Enrich.get_holidays(region=hi.region,
                                                      start_date=hi.start_date,
                                                      end_date=hi.end_date)
    return holidays

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="localhost", port=8080, reload=True)
```

**enrich.py**

```
from response_models import HolidaysOut
from typing import List
from datetime import date


class Enrich:
    @classmethod
    def get_holidays(cls, region: str, start_date: str, end_date: str) -> List[HolidaysOut]:
        final_list = []
        # do process incoming params here and generate the final list
        final_list = [{"name":"money", "date": date.today()},{"name":"sany", "date":date.today()}]
        return final_list
```

**response_models.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date

class HolidaysIn(BaseModel):
    region: str
    start_date: str
    end_date: str


class HolidaysOut(BaseModel):
    date: date
    name: str
```

**Input:**

```
{
  "region": "US",
  "start_date": "2019-01-01",
  "end_date": "2020-12-31"
}
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-27",
    "name": "money"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-27",
    "name": "sany"
  }
]
```